# Laravel Voyager Belongs To Many relationship displays "No results found"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, voyager

### Version information

- Laravel: v5.7.15
- Voyager: v1.1.10
- PHP: 7.2.8
- Database: MySQL 5.7.14

### Description

When I create a new belongs to many relationship, I cannot select Display field in the Voyager relationship creation popup, if I save anyway, I cannot select related entities when adding/editing the record.

### Steps To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:
I have a tables "products", "categories" and "category_product" (as per official, default Laravel naming convention, just to be sure). Category_product has two fields "product_id" and "category_id", both primary keys and indexes.

I go to product bread, which already exists, try to create a new relationship, see the image below

[image]

If I save anyway and try to add a new record I cannot select related categories (which surely exist, there are 4)

[image]

However, you can see there are 4 empty rows, that I can sort of select, but they contain no keys/labels as I wasn't been able to select them when I was creating the relationship.

Please, help me understand what I'm doing wrong, I already search a lot in GitHub and StackOverflow, I couldn't find this exact problem.

I have Product and Category and even CategoryProduct models created with table names defined. I tried a variety of relationship definitions in Laravel side, but I think they are not related. Now I have this:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_product');
}
```

Thank you for doing amazing work with Voyager, this is my first real struggle after months of use, which still makes it by far one of the best tools I have used in a long time.

This is edit view of the same bread and the same relationship

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run `composer require tcg/voyager dev-master` and test again. I have fix a similar issue and I think it may fix yours as well.

Comment: Omg, I cannot thank you more! Spent hours yesterday banging my head into this, apparently the dev branch has the fix. It was composer require tcg/voyager:1.x, but it did help right away, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome man. I am glad that I help you. Gladly will do again!!

Comment: i am facing same issue, also run this command but not working getting this error   [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package tcg/voyager in a version matching dev-master

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify "Full qualified Model Name"

see screenshot
[image]